# Swift. wkwebview does not respond to touch

Tags: ios, webview, wkwebview

I have a website that works in safari. but it doesn't work in webview.
When swiping, the game should work, but only the scrollbar (gray, on the right) reacts
, while everything works well in safari

Comment: Please, specify implicitly are you develeloping iOS app by yourslef, what IDE is used. If you are not able to change iOS app code - specify which technology is used to develop the website

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS app you are developing disable WKWebView scrolling:

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
```

Comment: it didn't help
+ need scrollView to work